# Literal content ('DataFormatString="{0:D6}"') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i wanted to display decimal two places value in my grid and I used DataFormatString.
Here is my asp.net code

```
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Value" DataField="Value" SortExpression="Value" DataFormatString"{0:F2}" />
```

but it is giving error

Literal content ('') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.

Comment: Your error message suggests that the code above is not the real code. Where is that equal sign?

Comment: yeah I just used with equal sign and it started working.

Comment: But the ASP.NET error suggests that you've already used the equal sign before you've asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm missing the `=`, so change

```
DataFormatString"{0:F2}"
```

to

```
DataFormatString="{0:F2}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you forgot to put the `=`:

```
DataFormatString="{0:F2}"
```